# C# Foreach Loop create all time a new File

Tags: c#

I would like to create a method that creates a new file for each supplier.

Unfortunately, my attempt doesn't work.

It is only create one file.

```
My List contains 
SupplierNr     ProofNr
13245242       45519013979
50945724       45519104207
50851942       45519130964
50940487       45519139065
13496912       45519139000
```

It should create 5 files not only one.

My Method

```
StreamWriter sw;
int filenumber = 1;
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
string filename = $"C:\\Users\\pasca\\Desktop\\Test\\i.lle_alt.{now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}{filenumber.ToString("D2")}";

foreach (string Supplier in SuppliersNr)
{
    int SPID = 0;

    sw = new StreamWriter(filename);

    for (int ID = 0; ID < CustomerProduct.Count; ID++)
    {
        sw.WriteLine($"{CustomerProduct[ID]};{DateBegin};{DateEnd};{Supplier};{Origin[ID]};{NonPreference[ID]};{ProofNr[SPID]};");
    }

    SPnr++;
    filenumber++;
    sw.Close();
}
```

Could you please explane me what i need to change, because i searched now a lot but doesn´t find any examples or something for my Question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although you increment `filenumber` you never update the variable `filename` inside the loop.

I would suggest to create a base filename part which is fixed (because it doesn't chage during the iteration:

```
string filenameBase = $"C:\\Users\\pasca\\Desktop\\Test\\i.lle_alt.{now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}"
```

and inside the loop change only the final part

```
foreach (string Supplier in SuppliersNr)
{
    sw = new StreamWriter(filenameBase + filenumber.ToString("D2"));
    filenumber++;       
}
```

you could actually get rid of the extra variable `filenumber` by using a normal for-loop. This way the increment will happen automatically:

```
for (int i = 0; i < SuppliersNr.Count; i++) //<- assuming that SuppliersNr is a List<string>
{
    sw = new StreamWriter(filenameBase + (i + 1).ToString("D2"));       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to put `filename` creation inside the `foreach` loop. Try like:

```
int filenumber = 1;
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;       
foreach (string Supplier in SuppliersNr)
{
  string filename = $"C:\\Users\\pasca\\Desktop\\Test\\i.lle_alt.{now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}{filenumber.ToString("D2")}";
  filenumber ++;
....
```

Answer (score 1):

`filename` is the same because you define it when `filenumber` was 1.
You need to update `filename` inside foreach loop:

```
foreach (string Supplier in SuppliersNr)
{
    int SPID = 0;
    filename = $"C:\\Users\\pasca\\Desktop\\Test\\i.lle_alt.{now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}{filenumber.ToString("D2")}";

    sw = new StreamWriter(filename);

    for (int ID = 0; ID < CustomerProduct.Count; ID++)
    {
        sw.WriteLine($"{CustomerProduct[ID]};{DateBegin};{DateEnd};{Supplier};{Origin[ID]};{NonPreference[ID]};{ProofNr[SPID]};");
    }

    SPnr++;
    filenumber++;
    sw.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the file name in this loop, like this:

```
            foreach (string Supplier in SuppliersNr)
            {
                string filename = $"C:\\Users\\pasca\\Desktop\\Test\\i.lle_alt.{now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")}{filenumber.ToString("D2")}";
                sw = new StreamWriter(filename);

                //your logic
                //fileNumber++;
            }
```